# NameError: name is not defined in Python

Tags: python

I have a function that when I prompt the user's input it works fine but when I try to call the function it shows me a message:"NameError: name is not defined in Python"

My goal is to generate bibformat
e.g.George R. R. Martin (1996). A Game of Thrones. New York City: Bantam Spectra.
My function is shown below.

```
def bibformat(author,title,city,publisher,year):
   return author+" ("+str(year)+"). "+title+". "+city+": "+publisher+"."
```

and the part that ask for user's input is shown below:

```
def bibformat_display():
   author=input("Author:")
   title=input("Title:")
   city=input("City:")
   publisher=input("Publisher:")
   year=input("Year:")
   print(bibformat(author,title,city,publisher,year))
```

When I try to run the code, the part that ask for user's input works fine

```
bibformat_display()
Author: George R. R. Martin
Title: A Game of Thrones
City: New York City
Publisher: Bantam Spectra
Year: 1996
George R. R. Martin (1996). A Game of Thrones. New York City: Bantam Spectra.
```

But when I try to call the function, it shows the error

```
bibformat(George R. R. Martin, A Game of Thrones, New York City, Bantam Spectra, 1996)
NameError: name 'sdfsa' is not defined
```

I was trying to change my function but it still not working, can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Use proper indentations in posted code

Comment: `sdfsa` does not appear in what you posted? Look at the line given bu the error

Comment: Didnt you find any better way to do so, use `f` strings for `return`, and quote around the names, like `bibformat('George R. R. Martin', 'A Game of Thrones', 'New York City', 'Bantam Spectra', 1996)`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a text without quotes so Python expects a variable.

### Solution

Put the text in quotes and  pass it  to the function like this:

```
bibformat('George R. R. Martin', 'A Game of Thrones', 'New York City', 'Bantam Spectra', 1996)
```